# Linq to entities and Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Driver Name")]
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class AdvancedDeductionElementVM : AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM
{
}

public class AdvancesDeductionDetailVM : AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM
{
}

public class AdvancesDeductionDeleteVM : AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM
{
}
```

expression:

```
    private Expression<Func<AdvancesDeduction, T>> GetAdvancesDeductionAbstractExpression<T>() where T : AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM, new()
    {
        Expression<Func<AdvancesDeduction, T>> projection = i =>
            new T()
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                Amount = i.Amount,
                DateTime = i.DateTime,
                Description = i.Description,
                DriverName = i.Driver.Name
            };
        return projection;
    }
```

and use it:

```
        AdvancesDeductionDetailVM model = (from i in db.AdvancesDeductions
                                           where i.ID == id.Value
                                           select i)
                                           .Select(GetAdvancesDeductionAbstractExpression<AdvancesDeductionDetailVM>()).FirstOrDefault();

        AdvancesDeductionDeleteVM model = (from i in db.AdvancesDeductions
                                           where i.ID == id.Value
                                           select i).Select(GetAdvancesDeductionAbstractExpression<AdvancesDeductionDeleteVM>()).FirstOrDefault();
```

It works, but I want to add it to Linq to entities, not using Lambda expression. Any way to use it?

Comment: What do you mean you want to add it to linq to entities

Comment: I want to have like (from i in db.AdvancesDeductions
                                           where i.ID == id.Value
                                           select MyFunction);

Comment: Don't get what you problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [NeinLinq](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq)
After that you can do

```
    [InjectLambda]
    public static bool To<T>(this AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM value) where T : AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM, new()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static Expression<Func<AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM,T>> To<T>() where T : AdvancedDeductionAbstractVM, new()
    {
        return i =>
            new T()
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                Amount = i.Amount,
                DateTime = i.DateTime,
                Description = i.Description,
                DriverName = i.Driver.Name
            };
    }
```

And use it like

```
AdvancesDeductionDetailVM model = (from i in db.AdvancesDeductions.ToInjectable()

                                           where i.ID == id.Value
                                           select i.To<AdvancesDeductionDetailVM>()).FirstOrDefault();
```